# WPF, share methods between two UserControl classes

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, user-controls, partial-classes

I have two `UserControl` classes, `RequiredFields` and `OptionalFields`.  I wanted to have a base class, `Fields`, that would inherit from `UserControl` and contain methods that both `RequiredFields` and `OptionalFields` would use.  However, when I try to do that, I get the following error:

> Partial declarations of 'MyNamespace.OptionalFields' must not specify different base classes

Here are my class definitions:

```
public partial class OptionalFields : Fields

public partial class RequiredFields : Fields

public abstract class Fields : UserControl
```

Even if I make `Fields` a `partial` class instead of `abstract`, or if I make it a regular non-abstract non-partial class, I get the same error.

Is what I'm wanting to do possible/reasonable?  If not, what is the best way of sharing methods between `UserControl` instances?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you have an OptionalFields.xaml?  If so, it is automatically generating OptionalFields.g.cs which contains the C# code that the XAML represents.  It contains a class that inherits from UserControl (or whatever the XAML's root element is).

Try changing the root element in the XAML file to Fields.

Comment: yup, you probably have still <UserControl> in your xaml instead of <local:Fields> or whatever.

Comment: Also, definitely shouldn't have my base class be `abstract` since then any user control that inherits from it will throw errors in the design view, saying it can't create an instance of the base class.

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to updated the other side of the partial?  I.e. is OptionalFields.Designer.cs inheriting from UserControl still?

Edit: sorry being too winforms, I of course mean OptionalFields.xaml